# Asbestos risk in my roof? What is this material?

Tags: roof, safety, attic, asbestos, materials

I'm a homeowner in London, and have recently started losing sleep over something.  Hoping somebody can shed some light!  Our next door neighbours are having their roof redone, and some manner of asbestos has been found (unclear what - roof tiles?).  This has made me aware for the first time that there could be some in our loft, where I've been storing all manner of things for years.  The front half of our roof is great and relatively new, but the back half is ancient and crumbling, though generally watertight.  I've ignored the steady rain of debris from it over the years, mumbling "must get something done about the roof."  Only now have I taken a close look with a bright-enough torch at just what is crumbling (see pictures).  It appears to be some kind of backing board on the old roof tiles (not back pointing, as I'd been assuming?).  Now losing sleep that this is AIB or some other asbestos-containing material that I and my family have been repeatedly exposed to dust/debris from.  Anybody have a clue what this is from the pics?
Have rung around a few asbestos surveyors, but not found availability yet.  Had assumed asbestos would come up on original house survey, but now wondering if loft was checked at all, as it may not have had a hatch at the time of purchase.  Any info appreciated - hopefully looking for reassurance that this material is harmless, whatever it is!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was chip board but when looking closer the fine layers do apear similar to a product that was used in the U.S. during the war when there was a wood shortage. I would not mess with it. If it felt brittle like cement flakes it is probably A product that contains asbestos. If it is not disturbed there is no real risk. If you are planning on remodeling or repairing the old roof area have it tested first so you and your family are safe.